# Can I open SaveFileDialog (windows.form) in WCF Service class?

Tags: ajax, wcf, extjs, savefiledialog, syncfusion

Need to generate document on the fly. for all the operation in application we are using WCF service.

(to generate the document we are plannign to use Syncfusion library, call is been made from ExtJs client and WCF service performs all db operation.)

Whats the possible solution for generating the document using WCF?

Comment: Is the document created on the server or client side? WCF is a server side technology and the end user won't have direct access to the server file system

Comment: file is getting created on server side (in WCF service method). Can I return binarystream or something?

Answer (score 0):

The WCF service is used to access the services from server in client mode, hence it’s not possible to open a Winforms application in WCF service. However you are trying the reverse action and we can’t  access the remote application in server.

Please refer the below link for further clarifications.

[How to create a file in WCF service application in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703786/how-to-create-a-file-in-wcf-service-application-in-windows)

Thanks,
AL.Solai.